# Empty EmbeddedDocument field?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

Can someone help me please? I'm trying to simply retrieve what's in the field "addresses". I can't get it to print anything other than empty braces "[]"

Here's an example record:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "51376F833EF9EB361F354ED0" },
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
      "suffix": "",
      "street_name": "FRANKLIN ST",
      "prefix": "",
      "zipcode": "49503",
      "state": "MA",
      "street_num": "127"
    }
  ],
  "created_at":{ "$date": 1361160419000.000000 }
}
```

Here's my class code:

```
class Buildings(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(required=True)
    addresses = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Address'))
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=False)
    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
        'indexes': ['_id'],
        'ordering': ['-created_at']
    }
class Address(db.EmbeddedDocument):
   city = db.StringField(required=False)
   suffix = db.StringField(required=False)
   street_name = db.StringField(required=False)
   zipcode = db.StringField(required=False)
   prefix = db.StringField(required=False)
   state = db.StringField(required=False)
   is_contracted = db.IntField(required=False)
   street_num = db.StringField(required=False)
```

And a loop that should print the embedded Document but only returns a [] for each object.

```
for building in Buildings.objects:
    print building.addresses
```

Any idea why this won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try check how your code store record in mongodb:

```
address = Address(**{
    "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
    "suffix": "",
    "street_name": "FRANKLIN ST",
    "prefix": "",
    "zipcode": "49503",
    "state": "MA",
    "street_num": "127"
})
Buildings(_id=ObjectId(), addresses=[address]).save()
```

You see next result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5146e17969d90d0f124536ee"),
    "addresses": [{
        "_types": ["Address" ],
        "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
        "suffix": "",
        "street_name": "FRANKLIN ST",
        "state": "MA",
        "zipcode": "49503",
        "prefix": "",
        "_cls": "Address",
        "street_num": "127"
    }],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2013-03-18T12:42:17.389Z")
}
```

I will implement your model as:

```
class Address(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    city = db.StringField()
    suffix = db.StringField()
    street_name = db.StringField()
    zipcode = db.StringField()
    prefix = db.StringField()
    state = db.StringField()
    is_contracted = db.IntField()
    street_num = db.StringField()

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
    }


class Buildings(db.Document):
    addresses = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Address))
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
        'indexes': ['_id'],
        'ordering': ['-created_at'],
    }
```

To store record as:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5146e2b069d90d0f2cc3911a"),
    "addresses": [{
        "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
        "suffix": "",
        "street_name": "FRANKLIN ST",
        "state": "MA",
        "zipcode": "49503",
        "prefix": "",
        "street_num": "127"
    }],
    "created_at": ISODate("2013-03-18T12:47:28.939Z")
}
```

I don't know how you save document with fields `"_id": { "$oid": "51376F833EF9EB361F354ED0"}` and `"created_at":{"$date": 1361160419000.000000}`, but I think that problem in it.

`required` field argument by default is `False`.

`EmbeddedDocumentField` and `ReferenceFiled` can get parameter as `EmbeddedDocument` and `Document` class or string (`'self'` for self reference).

If you want have id as object probably you must make it also in code.

If you want have another datetime format probably you must use `ComplexDateTimeField` or implement it with base class `ComplexDateTimeField`.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for me... and I'm not sure what's going on. Still prints a blank []

Comment: Can you help me understand what is not working between your example and mine?

Comment: Can you open mongo console and select any document from your collection `db.building.find()`, because your json example don't like as real mongo document (I can't insert your json to collention as `db.building.insert(your_json_there)`)? In my example I use `ObjectId` - default mongo id, in your code you also use that explicit. But your json `_id` have strange format. I think you have problems with id field.

Comment: I'm using PyMongo and MongoEngine so everything looks good I think. I have no problems querying records from other collections with $oid... It's ONLY the embedded document field I can't seem to grab